# My tablet is stuck on rebooting

Tags: samsung, tablet, password

I got a samsung t-mobile tablet (SM-T807T) and I forgot the password I got it to reboot but now it's stuck on "downloading" "do not turn off target!"
SO What Do I Do now?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the Tablet is Turned off before doing this. You should  do a [Master Reset](https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-16352).

- Press and hold the Power/Lock key and Up Volume key at the same time.
- Release the keys when the Android image appears.
- When the menu appears, press the Up Volume key to select wipe data / factory reset.
- Press the Power/Lock key to select.
- Press the Down Volume key to scroll to Yes – delete all user data.
- Press the Power/Lock key to select.
- Press the Power/Lock key to select reboot system now.